# ''setup cannot find office.en-us\dwtrig20.exe''

Tags: office-2010

During installation of Microsoft office 2010, I get the following error, which really confuses me:

> setup cannot find office.en-us\dwtrig20.

When I choose the folder that the office.en-us where dwtrig.exe file located it displays invalid destination.

Comment: This problem is related to some language settings. I had same issue, but surprisingly was able to install it using different language version. If you know Spanish/German/Russian/etc try to install that. There is probably a way to switch back to English later, although I wasnt able to do it in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason that makes such ''setup cannot find office.en-us\dwtrig20.exe'' error is that it may have some some fragments from the previously existing Ms Office.

please fix it with Fixer  [click here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9737366) to download and install. follow the instructions of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following page to fix your problem.

[how to fix ''setup cannot find office.en-us\dwtrig20.exe'' error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971179)